# Adding a DefaultAction type to my redux RootAction

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, union-types

I'm currently working on migrating a react-redux project to typescript which I'm relatively new to.

I've created a `RootAction` type which includes all of my app's action types, which I then use for typing my actions across the app (reducers, middleware, etc.). I did so based on this pattern:

```
type FooAction = FooAction1 | FooAction2 | FooAction3;
type BarAction = BarAction1 | BarAction2;

type RootAction = FooAction | BarAction;
```

I started running into issues when I tried adding a `DefaultAction` type to the possible action types which are included in my `RootAction`:

```
type DefaultAction = {
  type: string;
  meta?: any;
  payload?: any;
  error?: any
};

type RootAction = FooAction | BarAction | DefaultAction;`
```

I did so in order to deal with actions dispatched by some 3rd-party middleware I am using who's types and structures I can't always determine beforehand.

Here is the entire simplified example of the issue including the error I'm getting:

```js
//foo action types:
const Foo1 = 'Foo1';
const Foo2 = 'Foo2';

type Foo1ActionType = {
 type: typeof Foo1,
 payload: {
   a: string,
 }
};
type Foo2ActionType = {
 type: typeof Foo2,
 payload: {
   a: number,
 }
};

type FooAction = Foo1ActionType | Foo2ActionType;


//bar action type: 
const Bar = 'Bar'

type BarAction = {
 type: typeof Bar;
}


//default action type:  
type DefaultAction = {
 type: string;
 meta?: any;
 payload?: any;
 error?: any
};


//root action
type RootAction = FooAction | BarAction | DefaultAction


//reducer with unexpected behaviour (expect it to recognise Foo1ActionType and know it has a payload property):

function reducer(state={}, action:RootAction) {
 switch (action.type) {
   case Foo1: 
   return action.payload //Error: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'BarAction'.
   default:
     return state;
 }
}
```

You can see that if `DefaultAction` is removed from the `RootAction` everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?